# How to send sms using PlaySMS through a php script

Tags: php, web, server, sms, kannel

I am trying to use a PHP script to send sms. The sms gateway is Kannel and on top of which they are using PlaySMS Web-based Mobile Portal System for management.I know how I can send sms by directly communicating with Kannel HTTP sendsms interface using cURL to execute something like

(http://127.0.0.1:10200/cgi-bin/sendsms?user=myuser&pass=xyz&text=Hello&to=123456789&from=test)

But I want to use PlaySMS instead of directly communicating with the Kannel gateway.Is there some kind of PlaySMS HTTP interface used for sending sms same as that for Kannel's?.I want to use PHP code to achieve this funtionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question.Following steps should be followed

1>> Make sure you have a PlaySMS user account from your SMS gateway service provider.

2>> Enable webservices for your PlaySMS account and generate a webservices token.

3>> Now you need to send http POST or GET request to the server where PlaySMS is hosted.The basic request URL format is as follows.

http://"playSMS server here"/index.php?app=ws&u="user name here"&h="WebServices Token here"&op=pv&to="Number here"&msg="Msg HERE"

4>> More info on PlaySMS webservices URL can be found here
https://github.com/antonraharja/playSMS/blob/master/documents/development/WEBSERVICES.md

5>> After preparing the webservices URL with appropriate fields as per your need you now just need to send the request to the PlaySMS server.

6>> Use curl() or file_get_contents() to send the request,The procedure for using curl and sending GET request as follows:

```
$url = "http://fakeplaySMSserver.com/index.php?
app=ws&u=Test&h=bfcblablabla&op=pv&to=0335632121&msg=Hello!;

$ch = curl_init($url); // modify the webservices url as per your needs 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```